# How to create external/dynamic method in LINQ where clauses

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I would like to reuse code and create "where clauses" functions, for example:

```
this._repository.GetByExpression(x => 
                   x.StatusId.Equals(searchParameter.StatusId) &&
                   x.Priority == searchParameter.PriorityId.Value))
```

My wish would be to reuse those where clauses in various ways. or with a call or with multiple calls, for exemple:

```
this._repository.GetByExpression(x => myMethod(x))
```

Where myMethod looks like:

```
private Func<Entity, bool> myMethod(IList<Func<Entity.WorkOrder, bool>> x,SearchParameter.WorkOrderSearchParameter searchParameter) {return x.StatusId.Equals(searchParameter.StatusId) &&x.Priority == searchParameter.PriorityId.Value))
```

}

This way I will be able to reuse many calls LINQ

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: A `GetByExpression` extension on repository of whatever type?

Comment: For EF you need to realize that the Linq code is translated to SQL so that really limits what you can use as it cannot know how to translate just anything.

Comment: You can write something like: `public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T: class { ... }` and then pass it a lambda that is a valid EF predicate.  But, it has to be an Expression of T; that's easy to do with a lambda, and hard otherwise

Comment: Also no error pointed in your question...

Comment: Take a look at [Using the Specification Pattern for Querying](https://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/09/11/using-the-specification-pattern-for-querying/) document...

Comment: KISS >> DNRY  .. This adds complexity and introduces brittle conditions to your code. (I.e. EF still needs to be able to translate it into SQL)

Comment: You should probably look into [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).